# What privilege level do you have to be at to add a tag to a question?

Tags: discussion

This morning I tried to add the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag to a question. In my edit description I put "Added Python tag". I was given a message saying that it didn't appear that anything had changed. A minute later I got the message that another edit had been made to the post. They only thing the other edit did was add the Python tag (and their description was even "added Python tag".) So obviously it's possible to add just a tag to a question.

The [Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privilege) page doesn't say what level you have to be at to add a tag to a question. What privilege level do you have to be?

Comment: If it's an existing tag, any amount of rep, if it's a new tag, [1500 rep](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags).

Comment: It's not a new tag. Why wasn't I allowed to add it?

Comment: The other person probably edited just before you did. So the only change you made was already done, thus nothing to edit. So it's nothing wrong with the tag, just that someone else beat you to the punch.

Comment: Any screenshot?

Comment: No screenshot. I guess it's like everyone said, he must of just beaten me to the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anyone with any level of rep can add an existing tag to a post, but if you have less than 2k rep it will need to be approved by 3 users before being applied.

Your edit was unsuccessful because another user applied the edit after you loaded the page but before submitting the edit; had you submitted the edit before the other user you would have successfully submitted your edit for approval.